# Character unicode value

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a XML file encoded in UTF-8. When I open it in Java, some(in theory valid) characters remain encoded. For example, I try to get the `&#66352` character:

`String str = new String(line.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(str.charAt(pos));`

where pos is the position where it should be.
I get instead the `&` character.

When I open it with Notepad++ and make sure it encodes UTF-8, I get the same problem.

To my mind, there should be two ways: getting from the beginning only codes(no characters) or replacing all codes with characters.

What should I do and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please don't construct a String from a byte array without specifying a charset, thats alway a sign of a problem.
2. if the `charAt` returns the ampersand character then you are either not using an xml parser to load the file or the character is double encoded like `&amp;66352;`.
3. The character 66352 won't fit into Java's 16 bit char datatype and so gets encoded as two surrogate characters in a String. You should use the `codePointAt` method in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You need a proper XML parser. You can use some deserialization framework for that task (like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) or [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)), or use DOM parsing classes provided with Java: [org.w3c.dom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html)

Here is some example of using `org.w3c.dom` package: [How to read XML file in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

My personal preference is XStream library, however that might depend on the complexity of your XML file.

Comment: I don't have a XML syntax related problem. The thing is, some characters are not recognized, so a XML parser can't provide a solution

Comment: @Dragos: If there is something like this `<tag>&#66352</tag>` in your XML file, then only a XML parser can properly parse those symbols. Java has nothing to do with it.